# Including third party libraries in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, github

I am developing a wordpress plugin and would like to include third party libraries from Github. How do I include these a library so I can use the functions in my plugin?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please see the article [How do I ask a good question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include example of what you have tried so far (or at the very least what you have searched Google for).

Comment: Which part _exactly_ do you have issue with? In literal sense you just place library into folder and use like PHP code. The specifics of technical (and licensing) side can be much more intricate though.

Comment: i'm going to make aplugin for career jobs like a small CRM so i found some useful php scripts on github can i add them and use them in my plugin this plugin is for personal use i'm not going to sell it so no problem with licencing

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to use some sort of dependency management. You could use [`git submodules` (link to SCM page)](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or for e.g. [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

When you are using an autoloader (Composer ships with one) and have a [PSR-4 (Fig standard)](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) compliant autoloader (like Composer has), then you can just `use \Namespace\SubNamespace` and have everything available.